# Como inserir uma informação de uma model que possui um Relacionamento?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, controller

Tenho uma listagem de Produtos e nessa listagem possui o código do fornecedor, preciso inserir o nome do fornecedor nessa listagem.

Meu Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Produto> produtos = db.Produto
                                           .Include(p => p.Fornecedor)
                                           .Where(p => p.Ativo == true)
                                           .ToList();

        return View(produtos);

    }
```

Minha View

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
<tr>
    <th>
        Código
    </th>
    <th>
        Código do Fornecedor
    </th>
    <th>
       @* A informação há ser inserida *@
       Nome Fantasia
    </th>
    <th>
        Descricão
    </th>
    <th>
        Preco de Venda
    </th>
    <th>
        Quantidade
    </th>
    <th>
        Opções
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var produto in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.Codigo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.CodigoFornecedor)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.Descricao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.PrecoVenda)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.Quantidade)
        </td>

        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default details" data-id="@produto.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="@produto.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary edit" data-id="@produto.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
        <td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este seu caso não precisa de um *ViewModel*. Você pode usar apenas o *Model* de `Produto`.

Vamos primeiro tirar este `try... catch` que não é necessário no ASP.NET MVC. Depois vamos simplificar seus `Where` (`f => f.Ativo == true` e `f => f.Ativo` é a mesma coisa):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<Produto> produtos = db.Produto
                                      .Include(s => s.Fornecedores)
                                      .Where(s => s.Ativo)
                                      .ToList();

    return View(produtos);
}
```

Na *View*, use da seguinte forma:

```
@foreach (var produto in Model)
{
    foreach (var fornecedor in produto.Fornecedores)
    {
        <div>@fornecedor.Nome</div>
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Agora que você postou a *View*, atualize para:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
<tr>
    <th>
        Código
    </th>
    <th>
        Código do Fornecedor
    </th>
    <th>
        Nome do Fornecedor
    </th>
    <th>
       @* A informação há ser inserida *@
       Nome Fantasia
    </th>
    <th>
        Descricão
    </th>
    <th>
        Preco de Venda
    </th>
    <th>
        Quantidade
    </th>
    <th>
        Opções
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var produto in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.Codigo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.CodigoFornecedor)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.Fornecedor.Nome)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.Descricao)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.PrecoVenda)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => produto.Quantidade)
        </td>

        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default details" data-id="@produto.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="@produto.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary edit" data-id="@produto.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
        <td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Obrigado, simplificando assim ficou bem mais fácil, só não entendi direito como vai ficar a _View_, vou atualizar minha pergunta com a minha view para você me ajuda e também porque minha pergunta tomou um caminho diferente.

Comment: @J.C.Galhardi Veja se está de acordo.

Comment: Simples e objetivo. Meu ajudou muito.