# Como inserir uma informação em um objeto Json?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

Meu problema é parecido com dessa pergunta:
[Pergunta Stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101867/como-inserir-uma-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-uma-model-que-possui-um-relacionamento)

Porém nesse caso é usado o objeto **Json** para popular a tabela.

***Controller***

```
 public ActionResult GetDadosItensVenda(int? Codigo)
    {
        try
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

            List<ItensVenda> itensVenda = new List<ItensVenda>();

            itensVenda = db.ItensVenda.Include(s => s.Produto).Where(s => s.CodigoVenda == Codigo && s.Ativo == true).ToList();
            return Json(itensVenda, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

***Script***

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var CodigoVenda = @ViewBag.CodigoVenda;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Venda/GetDadosItensVenda?Codigo="+ CodigoVenda,
        success: function (itensVenda) {

            if (itensVenda != null) {
                var total = 0;

                $('#tbody').children().remove();

                $(itensVenda).each(function (i) {

                    total += (itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario * itensVenda[i].Quantidade);

                    var tbody = $('#tbody');
                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr +=
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Codigo;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].CodigoProduto;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Quantidade;
                    tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario;
                    tr += "<td>" + (itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario * itensVenda[i].Quantidade);
                    tbody.append(tr);
                });
            }
            $("#Total").html("<p>"+ total + "</p>");
        }
    });
});
```

Essa listagem funcionava normalmente, porém nessa listagem aparecia o código do produto, mas na verdade preciso informar a descrição desse produto e não o código.

Está dando o seguinte erro:
***Foi detectada uma referência circular ao serializar um objeto do tipo 'SistemaComercial.Models.ItensVenda'.***

Comment: Onde está a descrição do produto?

Comment: Na tabela Produto.  Coloquei `.Include(s => s.Produto)` para fazer o *JOIN*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sobre o erro da serialização circular, [implemente o conteúdo desta resposta para resolver](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35109/serializar-lista-de-objetos-para-json-a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-s/35153#35153).

E depois:

```
public ActionResult GetDadosItensVenda(int? Codigo)
{
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        List<ItensVenda> itensVenda = new List<ItensVenda>();

        itensVenda = db.ItensVenda.Include(s => s.Produto).Where(s => s.CodigoVenda == Codigo && s.Ativo == true).ToList();
        return Json(itensVenda.Select(i => new {
            i.Codigo,
            i.CodigoProduto,
            i.Quantidade,
            i.PrecoUnitario,
            Produto = i.Produto.Nome
        }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Não use `try... catch` em *Controller*. O ASP.NET MVC já trata exceção do jeito que precisa.

View:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var CodigoVenda = @ViewBag.CodigoVenda;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Venda/GetDadosItensVenda?Codigo="+ CodigoVenda,
            success: function (itensVenda) {

                if (itensVenda != null) {
                    var total = 0;

                    $('#tbody').children().remove();

                    $(itensVenda).each(function (i) {

                        total += (itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario * itensVenda[i].Quantidade);

                        var tbody = $('#tbody');
                        var tr = "<tr>";
                        tr +=
                        tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Codigo + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].CodigoProduto + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Produto + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].Quantidade + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario + "</td>";
                        tr += "<td>" + (itensVenda[i].PrecoUnitario * itensVenda[i].Quantidade) + "</td>";
                        tbody.append(tr);
                    });
                }
                $("#Total").html("<p>"+ total + "</p>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```